# EXCEL - Create a list of autorised values (without duplicate)

Tags: excel, vba, list, key-value-store

I have a list with a lot of date (some are duplicate or present many times).

```
Date        REF A          REF B
21/05/18    7134090-509 
21/05/18    A075124-605 
21/05/18    1371030-509 
22/05/18    A921069-501    CP0428419
22/05/18    CD2045-4       CP0716358
23/05/18    B811232MD501   CP1239676
28/05/18    41141026-501
```

I would like to create a list of autorised values that display each one of them, and that will update automatically when I add new rows on the previous list.

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyZpV.png)

```
Date
21/05/18
22/05/18
23/05/18
28/05/18
```

And I would like to use the selected date in VBA, so I would need to save it to a variable.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a new sheet named for exemple `values`, and define Ranges like `Date` on the `A:A` column.
Now you can store it in your variable

```
Set valuesSheet = Worksheets("values")
Set myDates = valuesSheet.Range("Date")
```

Now all your dates are stored in `myDates`

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer, but I think I was not clear enough. What I would like, is a dropdown list that display all unique values of the date. Thanks !